# How to map out array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to map out payment method objects that I receive from my server into an array of dictionaries. So far I have been able to get individual dictionaries but I haven't been able to put them into an array.

This is my struct that I want to use to map out the data:

```
struct PaymentMethod: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var brand: String
    var expMonth: Int
    var expYear: Int
    var last4: String
    
    init?(paymentDict: [String: Any]) {
        guard let card = paymentDict["card"] as? [String: Any] else {
            print("There is no \"card\" key or it's not a [String: Any] in: \(paymentDict)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let brand = card["brand"] as? String else {
            print("There is no \"brand\" key or it's not a String in: \(card)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let expMonth = card["exp_month"] as? Int else {
            print("There is no \"expMonth\" key or it's not a Int in: \(card)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let expYear = card["exp_year"] as? Int else {
            print("There is no \"expYear\" key or it's not a Int in: \(card)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let last4 = card["last4"] as? String else {
            print("There is no \"last4\" key or it's not a Int in: \(card)")
            return nil
        }
        self.brand = brand
        self.expMonth = expMonth
        self.expYear = expYear
        self.last4 = last4

    }
}
```

Using the above struct, I am able to print out each individual payment method object but I am not able to store them into an array of payment methods. I do that using the following function:

```
func listPaymentMethods(customerID: String) {
    
    FirebaseReferenceManager.functions.httpsCallable("listPaymentMethods").call(["customer_id": customerID]) { (response, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("failed to list customer's payment methods: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let response = response?.data as? [String: Any] {
            if let data = response["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                
                data.forEach { method in
                    if let payment = PaymentMethod(paymentDict: method) {
                        print("payment found \(payment)")
                    } else {
                        print("invalid payment")
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                print("No data in \(response)")
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

This prints out the following:

```
payment found PaymentMethod(id: Optional("495722B5-F311-4D15-BECC-A952F10FEDD3"), brand: "mastercard", expMonth: 4, expYear: 2025, last4: "4444")
```

and

```
payment found PaymentMethod(id: Optional("0C59C57F-5992-479B-8057-E6EF26E68389"), brand: "visa", expMonth: 12, expYear: 2045, last4: "4242")
```

I tried to modify my function to store the payment methods into an array of payment methods `@Published var paymentMethods = [PaymentMethod]()` but when I print the results, all of the data comes back as `nil`.

```
func listPaymentMethods(customerID: String) {
    
    FirebaseReferenceManager.functions.httpsCallable("listPaymentMethods").call(["customer_id": customerID]) { (response, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("failed to list customer's payment methods: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let response = response?.data as? [String: Any] {
            if let data = response["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                
                self.paymentMethods = data.map({ (card) -> PaymentMethod in
                    let brand = card["brand"] as? String ?? ""
                    let expMonth = card["exp_month"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let expYear = card["exp_year"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let last4 = card["last4"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    return PaymentMethod(brand: brand, expMonth: expMonth, expYear: expYear, last4: last4)

                })
                
                print(self.paymentMethods)
                
            } else {
                print("No data in \(response)")
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

printing `data = response["data"] as? [[String:Any]]` returns the following (this is the data that I am trying to map out):

```
[["object": payment_method, "billing_details": {
address =     {
    city = "<null>";
    country = US;
    line1 = "<null>";
    line2 = "<null>";
    "postal_code" = 45678;
    state = "<null>";
};
email = "<null>";
name = "<null>";
phone = "<null>";
}, "metadata": {
}, "created": 1622026254, "type": card, "livemode": 0, "customer": cus_JWaE2JEtbcI0JM, "card": {
brand = mastercard;
checks =     {
    "address_line1_check" = "<null>";
    "address_postal_code_check" = pass;
    "cvc_check" = pass;
};
country = US;
"exp_month" = 4;
"exp_year" = 2025;
fingerprint = jI4Pm7ac3fZjdYDN;
funding = credit;
"generated_from" = "<null>";
last4 = 4444;
networks =     {
    available =         (
        mastercard
    );
    preferred = "<null>";
};
"three_d_secure_usage" =     {
    supported = 1;
};
wallet = "<null>";
}, "id": pm_1IvKK9LVD5W50FFKvSbe2eA0], ["customer": cus_JWaE2JEtbcI0JM, "livemode": 0, "type": card, "id": pm_1IuyMzLVD5W50FFK2heBUTai, "billing_details": {
address =     {
    city = "<null>";
    country = US;
    line1 = "<null>";
    line2 = "<null>";
    "postal_code" = 123456;
    state = "<null>";
};
email = "<null>";
name = "<null>";
phone = "<null>";
}, "metadata": {
}, "created": 1621941861, "card": {
brand = visa;
checks =     {
    "address_line1_check" = "<null>";
    "address_postal_code_check" = pass;
    "cvc_check" = pass;
};
country = US;
"exp_month" = 12;
"exp_year" = 2045;
fingerprint = KKSbyUhUcKKSyto0;
funding = credit;
"generated_from" = "<null>";
last4 = 4242;
networks =     {
    available =         (
        visa
    );
    preferred = "<null>";
};
"three_d_secure_usage" =     {
    supported = 1;
};
wallet = "<null>";
}, "object": payment_method]]
```

The only data that I want to map out is the brand, expiration month and year, and the last 4 digits of the credit card number.

MOST RECENT VERSION

```
if let response = response?.data as? [String: Any] {
if let data = response["data"] as? [String: Any] {
    if let card = data["card"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        self.paymentMethods = card.map({ (card) -> PaymentMethod in
            let brand = card["brand"] as? String ?? ""
            let expMonth = card["exp_month"] as? Int ?? 0
            let expYear = card["exp_year"] as? Int ?? 0
            let last4 = card["last4"] as? String ?? ""
            
            return PaymentMethod(brand: brand, expMonth: expMonth, expYear: expYear, last4: last4)
            
        })
        
    }
    
}
print(self.paymentMethods)
```

}

Any help would be very much appreciated thank you! :)

Comment: Why not just use `self.paymentMethods = data.map { PaymentMethod($0) }`?

Comment: Also, the reason is that in your `PaymentMethod`-struct you get a `card`-Dictionary from the `paymentDict`, and then all information from that card while in the other example, you try to get all the information from the data itself

Comment: @Schottky How could I get the card dictionary using the second method?

Comment: Just the same way as you did in the first: `let card = data["card"] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]` and then take all your data from there

Comment: @Schottky I added it above under "MOST RECENT VERSION" but this returns an empty array

Comment: What I meant is to put the `data["card"]` inside the map method, so something like `if let data = response["data"] as? [[String:Any]]; data.map { billingDetails -> if let card = billingDetails["card"]  ... }`

Comment: @Schottky yep that worked perfectly. If you want to put that in an answer I'll set it as the accepted answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reiterate the comments:
The issue here is that in the line `self.paymentMethods = data.map({ (card) -> PaymentMethod in ...`, the card is not a card (`[String:Any]`), but a whole data-object with a lot of information. So to fix this issue you simply have to get the `card` from the `data`-object like so:

```swift
self.paymentMethods = data.map { billingDetails in
    let card = billingDetails["card"] ?? [:]
    let brand = card["brand"] as? String ?? ""
    let expMonth = card["exp_month"] as? Int ?? 0
    let expYear = card["exp_year"] as? Int ?? 0
    let last4 = card["last4"] as? String ?? ""
                    
    return PaymentMethod(brand: brand, expMonth: expMonth, expYear: expYear, last4: last4)

}
```